# What lots give the Beautiful Vista moodlet in Isla Paradiso?

Tags: the-sims-3

Isla Paradiso is the world included in the *Island Paradise* expansion pack for *The Sims 3*. What lots give the Beautiful Vista moodlet in that town, and what are the values? The only location I know of is 1 Alto Road, which gives a +30 moodlet.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you can achieve "Beautiful Vista" just by having a "Beautifully Decorated" home with landscaping.

I have had "Beautiful Vista" at all my houses, regardless of the lot.

I think this may actually have something to do with the size of the house as well, since I have achieved "beautiful vista" before the rooms were "Beautifully Decorated".

Regardless, all my homes in Bridgeport, Sunset Valley, & my vacation homes in World Adventures, have had that moodlet.

Answer (score -2):

Beautiful Vista is a place/lot attribute. Certain lots can provide the Beautiful Vista moodlet, these are usually found on some of the pre-packaged lots in the game. Bulldozing these lots will also remove the Beautiful Vista attribute and any new lots placed on that location will no longer provide the Beautiful Vista moodlet.

You can, however, *modify* the existing lot and place a home there. The game is a little finicky about the Beautiful Vista attribute when modifying lots, so be careful. It seems that most of these Beautiful Vista lots are found along the beach. I have found two of following to be "Beautiful Vistas":

- 15 Summer Hill Court (Sunset Valley)
- 345 Riverblossom Hills Drive (Riverview)

Comment: He's talkin' about a specific neighborhood, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Ugh, that teaches me to answer questions three hours after I should be in bed.

Comment: Also, I believe your first point to be in error. You can in fact completely bulldoze the building on a Beautiful Vista lot and still receive the moodlet, even on the empty lot itself, and build from scratch with the same result. At least in the case of the known Isla Paradiso lots.

Comment: @Teryx I specified Bulldoze to refer to the Edit Neighborhood tool. The Beautiful Lot buff is an attribute on the lot directly that cannot be modified by in-game player tools. Choosing to bulldoze the lot (in neighborhood view) removes this attribute, but deleting existing buildings in build mode allows it to stick around.

Comment: @RavenDreamer You're mistaken, at least as of Island Paradise - it's possible that this feature was added in that expansion or a later patch. I was also referring to the Edit Neighbourhood tool, you can in fact bulldoze a lot and still receive the Beautiful Vista moodlet on the empty lot or on any subsequent structures you build on it. I know this from experience, as of yesterday, testing this on 1 Alto Road.

Comment: @Teryx Huh, then I'm glad EAxis got around to patching that. I don't own anything past Ambitions, so I'll defer to you in this.